# Jmeter trim whitespaces from a SOAP Request

Tags: jmeter, soapui

I have a scenario where I have sample request in SOAP UI and I want to run those webservice in JMeter.

The issue I have encountered is as follows:

In SOAP UI, we have property "Strip Whitespaces". When set to true, I get the expected output.
However in JMeter, there is no such property hence my request via JMeter are not successful.

Is there anyway to strip whitespaces from whole request not just from variables in JMeter.
Can BeanShell Preprocessor help me?

The sample request which doesnot work in JMETER is something like this:

```
      <Envelope>
            <Header>ABC</Header>
            <Body>
                 <Param1></Param1>
                 <Param2></Param2>
             </Body>
      </Envelope>
```

The sample request which works and give expected output in JMeter is:

```
<Envelope><Header>ABC</Header><Body><Param1></Param1><Param2></Param2></Body>/Envelope>
```

Comment: Which version of JMeter do you use? I work with 2.11 and it allows me to send the request like the first one, i.e. with indents and whitespaces.

Comment: @olyv I am also using the same version. But I get error when I send with indents and whitespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a [Beanshell Pre Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) **as a child** of the request which data you want to change
2. Place the following code into "Script" section

   ```
   String data = sampler.getXmlData();
   data = data.replaceAll(" ",""); 
   data = data.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"),"");
   sampler.setXmlData(data);
   ```
3. Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) Listener and inspect what's being sent.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more details on how the power of scripting can be used to enhance your JMeter tests.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. But I want to delete whitespaces between ">" and "<". As I want preserve whitespaces in namespace elements like: <element1"whitespace"xmlns="Some url">. 
In above example I have an whitespace between element1 and xmlns. Do we have RegEx in BeanShell Pre Processor

Comment: the java replaceAll function quoted above does accept regular expressions.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)